# How can I find my deleted question & answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

There's a question I asked several years ago (about quantum mechanics and nonlinearity) which have been deleted. How can I find them?

Comment: Perhaps [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374784/parallel-universes-and-quantum-nonlinearity) or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377839/non-linear-quantum-mechanics-and-the-many-worlds-interpretation)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have 10k reputation, you should be able to search for your own deleted questions just with the query `deleted:yes`. [Link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A177855+deleted%3Ayes). A user without 10k reputation would have to ask a moderator for help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need 10k reputation to see your deleted questions/ answers?

Comment: @Jakob You don't, if you have a link to the post. The search engine doesn't include deleted posts if you are under 10k, though, so it can be hard to find them. This is a network-wide thing, not something that we have any control over.